# Google Analytics Filter can NOT apply to Past Data?

Tags: google-analytics

I just know that the GA filters can't apply to historical data, so does it mean the filter would only apply to the date while it enabled?
For example, I added an IP address filter at 15th Aug, then removed it at 16th Aug. Then the report will always filter that IP address's data at 15 Aug, even after I removed the filter, is it working like that??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is how it will work.  It's a good idea to always have a separate master profile that remains unfiltered, in case you do something like this and need the data from that filtered period.

Comment: I heard that custom report can apply filter to past data..so is it also ongoing report just like standard report?  Thanks.

Comment: Custom reports can refine your data without permanently altering it, just like a standard report.  But, you would need to make a custom report for each metric you wanted to analyze.  Perhaps you should look into "advanced segments" to filter all of your data without permanent changes made to it.

Comment: Yes, I found advanced segments too, but Profile filter seems to be most powerful, at least I can't do ip address filter by other alternatives. thanks.