# Google Analytics filter 'Ashburn' not working on view

Tags: google-analytics, bots, google-analytics-filters

I've added a filter to my website to filter Ashburn bot traffic (a known bot traffic problem), however it seems that is not applying into my view.
Am I doing anything wrong with the filter? The spikes you see in the graphic are from the bots.

Filter:
[image: Filter]

View Graphic:
[image: View Graphic]

Ashburn:
[image: Ashburn]

PS: Sorry, couldn't find where I could change the language to EN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View filters are not retroactive; they filter data as it is *incoming* to the view, but they won't remove hits that are *already* recorded at the time of adding the filter. So, even if your filter is working, you won't see the past bot traffic disappear in your view. And if it is working, you should stop seeing **new** traffic appear that is blocked by the filter, although it can [take up 24 hours](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162#limits) for the filter to kick in, as per the docs.

[The docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162) don't speak clearly on this topic (although they do make sure to use the term *incoming* to imply the non-retroactive implementation), but you can find many instances where this behavior is noted:

- [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27516655/11447682)
- [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11958946/11447682)
- [Webmasters StackExchange QA](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/100126)

The only way to hide those past hits in your view is to set up a [custom segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493), that filters on the same condition as the view filter you set up, and have it selected whenever you want to filter out that traffic in the current section you are looking at.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I created another view. I really thought it would 'refresh' my View, when I apply a new filter.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's not how GA works and they could really make the guides more helpful at pointing this out. Glad that this helped, and I'm glad you created a new view; that is one of the best steps to take in this scenario to get clean data moving forward.